# VBA randomly stops executing loop due to internet break. How to resume when Internet comes back on?

Tags: html, vba, excel, internet-explorer

I have written VBA code to extract data from Yahoo Finance. For the most part, the code is doing its job and extracting what I want it to. However, every so often, it gets stuck while it loops through different companies and the whole code stops working. I suspect that this might be occurring due to the internet connection momentarily breaking when it is looping through a particular company. To be specific, I think this is occurring in the following block of my code:

```
For i = 1 To 14
   .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=" & Arrays(i) & "+Historical+Prices"
   Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop
   Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop here
```

Where the internet most likely breaks as it is trying to navigate the ith company (Arrays(i)) and causes the code to loop infinitely at `Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop.ReadyState <>4`. For some reason, the code doesn't work even after the internet switches back on and just keeps getting stuck trying to execute navigation to this ith Arrays. Why might this be? Is there a way to correct this?

Note: It works perfectly if I End the execution of the Macro and restart it.

Here is the full block of code for your reference.

```
Sub GetYahooFinanceTable()
    Dim sURL As String, sResult As String
    Dim oResult As Variant, oData As Variant, R As Long, C As Long, Arrays(30) As String, IE As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    For i = 1 To 14
        Arrays(i) = Sheets("List of Companies").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
       .Visible = False
       For i = 1 To 14
           .navigate "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=" & Arrays(i) & "+Historical+Prices"
           Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop
           Do While .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
           With .document
              Sheets("Data Pull Adj Close Yahoo").Cells(3, 7 * i) = .getElementById("yfs_l84_" & Arrays(i)).innerText
           End With
       Next i
    End With
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you guys have any insights?

Comment: I am bumping this question. I would really find it helpful if you could take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work. But did you try using the `Sleep` function? I would try insering it like this:

With `.document`

```
Sheets("Data Pull Adj Close Yahoo").Cells(3, 7 * i) =
    .getElementById("yfs_l84_" & Arrays(i)).innerText
Sleep 10000
...
```